# How to get the value of a promise with rest call

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the id returned and logged in the WORK function. What seems to occur is I either get a promise or 'undefined' on console.log depending on how I tweek this. Having watched multiple videos, played in Mozilla's javascript examples I have no idea how to get this to work. The examples I have found seem to be quite complicated, and not exactly clear on how to resolve.

```
async function WORK() {
  console.log('starting this pos');
  const response = await gatherdata();
  console.log(response);
  }
WORK();
```

Then the Request Function

```
  const request = require('request-promise');
  async function gatherdata() {
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://SERVICE.LOCAL:8089/services/search/jobs',
        'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Basic dfasdfasdfasdf',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
        'data': 'thing',
        'output_mode': 'json'
        }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        return JSON.parse(response.body).id;
    });
    
    };
```

Comment: `Promise` returned by `gatherData()` function fulfills with `undefined` value because this function doesn't explicitly returns any value. You need to return something from this function and returning anything from the callback function of `request(...)` won't make it a return value of the outer function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gatherdata()` doesn't return anything.  Return the promise for the asyncronous operation it invokes:

```
return request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return JSON.parse(response.body).id;
});
```

Comment: This resolved it. I thought the code below was doing the return. 

    `return JSON.parse(response.body).id;`

Comment: @james: That returns from the callback function, but `gatherdata` itself contains no `return`.  One is contained within the other, but they're different functions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something from your `gatherdata()` function .As I see you are using `request-promise` you can `await` the `request` and return the data

```
const request = require('request-promise');
      
async function gatherdata() {
   var options = {
     'method': 'POST',
     'url': 'https://SERVICE.LOCAL:8089/services/search/jobs',
     'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Basic dfasdfasdfasdf',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      form: {
        'data': 'thing',
        'output_mode': 'json'
      }
   };
   
   return await request(options); // this will return the data you get from api call
       
};
```

Comment: `await` in `return await request(options)` is unnecessary. `return request(options)` is enough.

Comment: Yeah it is ,but I guess this is much cleaner way when you are already returning something from an async function .